# User-written code to create macro, how to debug

Tags: sas-macro, sas-dis

In SAS DI studio I'm attempting to create a macro, and assign a value to it with a user written code transformation. How do I print the value of this macro to test if my code does what I want it to do.

I need a macro that takes a value based on the date when the project is run looking something like:

```
%let runYear = if month < 6 then year(today) - 1 else year(today)
```

Normally I would start with something simple like:

```
%let test = month(today())
```

And just look what that gives me and work it out, but I don't know how to display the value of 'test' in above example.

I am new to SAS DI studio and I realize this is a simple question but I couldn't find the answer. All I want to know is how to print a value from user written code / how do debug user written code.

Comment: Note that in SAS a macro is a function.  What you are talking about is a what most users call a macro variable.  In the documentation will see them referred to as symbols.

Answer (score 0):

To reference the value of a macro variable you use `&` before the name of the macro variable. So if the macro variable is named `test` then use `&test` for the value stored in test.

To display the value of a macro variable you could use the `%put` macro statement.

```
%put &test ;
```

The `%put` statement allows a special syntax that will display the name of the macro variable before the value.

```
%put &=test ;
```

Note that in your case the vlaue stored in your macro variable is just the text you displayed. So test has the string `month(today())`. That will work well if you expand the macro variable's value in the middle of a SAS statement as SAS will evaluate that string as a call to the month() and today() functions.  But if you expected the macro variable to contain the result of those functions you would need to wrap each function call inside a call to the macro function `%sysfunc()`.  Example:

```
151   %let test = month(today());
152   %put &=test;
TEST=month(today())
153
154   %let test = %sysfunc(month(%sysfunc(today())));
155   %put &=test;
TEST=7
```